# Pandas group by changes unique value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset, one of the column has two unique value:

```
[In]: data.payout_policy.unique()

[Out]: [upfront, consignment]
Categories (2, object): [upfront, consignment]
```

So "Payout_Policy" has two unique value. However when I used group by for this field something strange happens:

```
[In]: partition = data.groupby(by=['payout_policy'])
partition.payout_policy.unique()

payout_policy
1099                              [], Categories (0, object): []
1199                              [], Categories (0, object): []
1299                              [], Categories (0, object): []
1399                              [], Categories (0, object): []
1499                              [], Categories (0, object): []
1599                              [], Categories (0, object): []
...
999                               [], Categories (0, object): []
consignment    [consignment]
Categories (1, object): [consign...
upfront              [upfront]
Categories (1, object): [upfront]
```

why the unique value of the same field is different in this case?

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: What is partition_set?

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: `partition.payout_policy` is a `SeriesGroupBy` object, it is not the column in your dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen Rauch pointed out, you are looking at a `SeriesGroupby` object. If you want to access the groups keys, you can use the `groups` attribute as written in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-object-attributes). To output all the keys of your group object, use :

```
partition.groups.keys()
```

It should yield you the same output as

```
data.payout_policy.unique()
```